# Representation dimension of Auslander algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Is the representation dimension of Auslander algebras known? Is there an example of such algebras with representation dimension larger than 4?

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic comment, but I've been meaning to ask you: where does one start learning about the (interplay of) representation theory and homological algebra of **finite-dimensional associative algebras**? I find such algebras very interesting and would like to learn more about them.

Comment: @July My favorite books about the topic are Frobenius algebras I and II by Skowronski and Yamagata. For deeper homological algebra topics (for example derived categories) you can also look at the book by Zimmermann.